# Graphs on Windows Forms using C# (.NET 2.0)

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, graph

Is there an Open Source Free Graph Control for Windows Forms .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [nPlot](http://www.nplot.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) for a while. You can generate various types of graphs that look very professional.